# Talend - Read file from several FTP SERVER

Tags: ftp, jobs, talend

I have several FTP servers (4 servers), where there are files that are generated by an application. 
This application generates the same type of file with the same structure in the 4 servers.
With Talend, I want to when any change to a file in one of the servers I need to recover their data and put in in Active MQ.

What could you suggest ? Because in tFTP I don't have tWaitForFile

Answer (score 0):

Staying within that architectural approach... You could poll the ftp servers to detect a change in a file's updated Timestamp or size .